# Send e-mail code is sending a blank file, unless the template is saved first

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is used in other files to send in effect a form for review and approval, but within this workbook for some reason I am getting blank files sent and the content added by the users is lost.  I know this isn't a code checking service, but I was wondering have I missed something with this - so I need to have the file 'saved' before it is attached to the e-mail?

```
    'Open e-mail and create a new message
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim SubmitEMail As String: SubmitEMail = ws.Range("U1").Value


' set the requirements for the new message
With newmsg
    .Recipients.Add SubmitEMail
    .CC = ws.Range("U2").Value
    .Subject = "New Concession request form submitted"
'use string defined above as the main body of the message
    .Body = "Dear " & Location & "," & vbLf & vbLf & "Please find attached: a new Concession request.  Please review and indicate Concession number, or provide details of amendments needed." & vbLf & vbLf & "Regards," & vbLf & vbLf & SenderName
    .Attachments.Add wb.FullName
    .Display
End With
End If

MsgBox "Please review the E-Mail, Adding any additional recipients as required. add your signature and send to complete the submission"
```

The e-mail sending bit works perfectly, but the attachment is always blank, the data the user has added is lost (if the user saves the workbook first on their local station) the process works perfectly, but I am wanting to avoid asking them to so this - potentially creates 2 versions of a document where I only want one)

Comment: yeah, you cannot attach it unless it is saved and has a valid filename. is that a problem?

Comment: yes and no, ideally I didn't want the user to have to save the file, as we could end up with duplicates which is a big problem for audits, and things.  But I added a temporary filename process to the sheet (which I had previously removed, believing it wasn't necessary).  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug your sub and use `Debug.Print wb.FullName` without saving wb - you'll get only "Book(n)" name. For your case I may suggest following solution:

```vb
Dim fileName As String


' save to temp directory
wb.SaveAs Environ("TEMP") & wb.Name & ".xlsx"

' save the full name to string variable
fileName = wb.FullName

' close the file in order to be able to delete it
wb.Close

'[attach the file
'.Attachments.Add fileName
' and do other stuff you need]


' delete temporary file
Kill fileName
```

This will also allow you to avoid asking users to save file and they even won't know about this.

Comment: Vitaly,  Thanks, this is what I did in the end up - I had previously removed much messier code doing the same thing, thinking I didn't need it.  I know better now

Answer (score 0):

You need a saved Workbook to attach. If you want to make sure there are no unneeded duplicates, you can do the following:

- Save a copy of the workbook in a temp folder (with `SaveCopyAs`)
- attach this copy to the email and display
- delete the copy in the temp folder